# JSF Apache MyFaces 2.0 not working correctly

Tags: java, primefaces, myfaces

I create a project with Spring 4.0.3 and JSF Apache MyFaces 2.0.
I found a problem when trying to add a new Employee, `the Add button` cannot function unless after 2 clicks instead of one simple click.

`Add icon` on `list page`

```html
<p:commandLink action="add?faces-redirect=true">
    <h:graphicImage value="/resources/pictures/add.ico"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Once I click (2 clicks) on `Add icon` on `list page`, I redirect to `add page` and there's what displayed on console.

```js
18:59:55,575 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (MSC service thread 1-1) Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
18:59:55,618 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_CLEAR_JAVASCRIPT_FOR_BUTTON' found, using default value false
18:59:55,618 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_HIDDEN_FIELDS_FOR_LINK_PARAMS' found, using default value false
18:59:55,618 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.SAVE_FORM_SUBMIT_LINK_IE' found, using default value false
18:59:55,618 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.READONLY_AS_DISABLED_FOR_SELECTS' found, using default value true
18:59:55,618 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_VIEWSTATE_ID' found, using default value true
18:59:55,618 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_XHTML_LINKS' found, using default value true
18:59:55,618 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_FORM_SUBMIT_SCRIPT_INLINE' found, using default value false
18:59:55,618 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CONFIG_REFRESH_PERIOD' found, using default value 2
18:59:55,618 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.VIEWSTATE_JAVASCRIPT' found, using default value false
18:59:55,618 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.REFRESH_TRANSIENT_BUILD_ON_PSS' found, using default value auto
18:59:55,618 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.REFRESH_TRANSIENT_BUILD_ON_PSS_PRESERVE_STATE' found, using default value false
18:59:55,634 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.VALIDATE_XML' found, using default value false
18:59:55,634 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.WRAP_SCRIPT_CONTENT_WITH_XML_COMMENT_TAG' found, using default value true
18:59:55,634 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) Tomahawk jar not available. Autoscrolling, DetectJavascript, AddResourceClass and CheckExtensionsFilter are disabled now.
18:59:55,634 SEVERE [org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) Both MyFaces and the RI are on your classpath. Please make sure to use only one of the two JSF-implementations.
18:59:55,650 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) Reading standard config META-INF/standard-faces-config.xml
18:59:56,375 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) Reading config : vfs:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/JPAHibernateSpring.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5.0.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
18:59:56,390 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) Reading config /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
18:59:56,390 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : myfaces-api not found.
18:59:56,390 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : myfaces-impl not found.
18:59:56,390 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : tomahawk not found.
18:59:56,406 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : tomahawk12 not found.
18:59:56,406 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : tomahawk-sandbox not found.
18:59:56,406 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : tomahawk-sandbox12 not found.
18:59:56,406 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : tomahawk-sandbox15 not found.
18:59:56,406 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : myfaces-orchestra-core not found.
18:59:56,406 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : myfaces-orchestra-core12 not found.
18:59:56,406 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : trinidad-api not found.
18:59:56,406 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : trinidad-impl not found.
18:59:56,406 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : tobago not found.
18:59:56,406 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : commons-el not found.
18:59:56,406 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces-package : jsp-api not found.
18:59:56,406 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.util.ExternalSpecifications] (MSC service thread 1-1) MyFaces Bean Validation support enabled
18:59:57,003 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) Serialization provider : class org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.serial.DefaultSerialFactory
18:59:57,014 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultLifecycleProviderFactory] (MSC service thread 1-1) Using LifecycleProvider java.lang.String
18:59:57,014 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer] (MSC service thread 1-1) ServletContext 'D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\JPAHibernateSpring.war\' initialized.
18:59:57,014 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (MSC service thread 1-1) Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
```

Have you please any idea about this issue: why should I click 2 times on `Add icon` to redirect from `list page` to the `add page`.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information and include some codes in order to understand and detect the issue, Your question is so vague

Comment: Hello YouYou, I added the required files, could you please take a look.

Comment: Could you please try to isolate the problem? The code is full of non-problem-related pieces. Take a look to how to ask a good question with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry YouYou for the bad question. I hope it is now clear.